# How to change AVD path from default path

Tags: android-emulator

I am getting  the following error when i try to run my AVD

**NAND: could not write file C:\DOCUME~1....\LOCALS~1\Temp\2\AndroidEmulator\TMP7.tmp, No space left on device.**

My SDK is NOT located  in C: .Is there any way to change the path of the temp file being generated by AVD.

After searching on internet ,i have tried following , but none worked.

1. Created user variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME pointing to a path NOT in C:.
2. Deleted and recreated the AVD .

*PS: On the server where i work , I cannot increase my quota on C: , that's why need to move out of it.*

Thanks

Comment: For a workaround , i mapped my temp and tmp folders to a new path which is not in c: , but i am still interted in knowing if this could have been done in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

That was auto Generated file .you have to remove from this path

- Start > Run > %temp% > cltra+a > delete all.

Hope this will solve your problem and open your emulator properly.

Comment: Actually cleaning  the temp folder all the time will not help my cause.

Answer (score 1):

As Manik said, a solution could be to make a symbolic link to another location :

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\{you}\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator" "{new-location}"
```